# Interactive switching of value fields in Quicksight Visuals

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I'm sure this is a pretty noob question, but I am stuck. I have found a tutorial on how to use parameters to set switch between fields here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=Dk9NtZbH2Hw I was wondering if there is a way to do this with value fields, like say on a heat map visual, to be able to switch between revenue and cost via dropdown?  I can not get a ifelse formula to work with these types for fields.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know much about the specifics of your data or the error, but similar to the video, you could create a parameter with manual values "Revenue" and "Cost" and set that as the dropdown control on the plot, then create a calculated field:

`ifelse(${parameter} = "Revenue", {revenueFieldName}, ${parameter} = "Cost", {costFieldName}, "Some Default")`

Then in the heatmap value field, use this new calculated field instead, and it should toggle based on the parameter.